# How can TWIG output the attribute of object from pimcore_relation() in AreaBrick in Pimcore

Tags: pimcore

I have AreaBrick template which is used both by CMS pages and Controller templates:

```
{% set phrase_field = pimcore_input(
  'phrase',
  {
    'placeholder': 'website.phrase'|trans,
    "reload": true,
    "width": 600
  }
) %}
{% if phrase is not defined or phrase is empty %}
  {% set phrase = phrase_field.data %}
{% endif %}


{% set company_field = pimcore_relation(
  'companyRelation',
  {
    "types": ["object"],
    "classes": ["Company"],
    "reload": true,
    "width": 600
  }
) %}
{# company_name can be provided from controller rendering template #}
{% if company_name is not defined or company_name is empty %}
  {% set company_name = company_field.data %}
{% endif %}


{% if editmode %}
{{ phrase_field|raw }}  
{{ company_field|raw }}  
{% endif %}


{{ phrase }}
{{ company_name.name }}
```

It works perfect with string fields pimcore_input.
But for relations pimcore_relation I can get only object ID. How can I output some property of related object? I used the attribute 'name' for example

In this example company_name has value:

```
array:3 [▼
  "id" => 1234
  "type" => "object"
  "subtype" => "object"
]
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to use 'action' function for CMS pages
and to 'with' string variable in Controllers.

Areabrick:

```
class SomeAreaBrick extends AbstractTemplateAreabrick
{
    public function action(Info $info): void
    {
        $name = '';
        try {
            $companyRelation = $info->getDocumentElement('companyRelation');
            if ($companyRelation instanceof Relation) {
                $company = $companyRelation->getElement();
                if ($company instanceof Company) {
                    $name = $company->getName();
                }
            }
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            // do nothing
        }
        $info->setParam('company_name', $name);
    }
}
```

Template rendered by Controller uses the same custom AreaBrick:

```
{{ include('@SomeBundle/areas/some-area-brick/view.html.twig', {'company_name': some_variable|default('')}) }}
```